# In go, how do I use a closure with a gorilla/mux subrouter?

Tags: go, gorilla

There seem to be all sorts of examples of using a HandlerFunc closure similar to this one: http://codegangsta.gitbooks.io/building-web-apps-with-go/content/controllers/README.html

However I can't get it to work with a subrouter. Example:

```
func MyHandler(renderer *render.Render) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        renderer.HTML(rw, http.StatusOK, "subroute/index", nil)
    })
}

func main() {
    renderer := render.New(render.Options{Layout: "base"})
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(false)

    router.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ...
    })

    subroutes := router.Path("/subroute").Subrouter()
    subroutes.Methods("GET").HandlerFunc(MyHandler(renderer))

    http.Handle("/", router)

    log.Println("Listening...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

Gives me this error:

```
cannot use MyHandler(renderer) (type http.Handler) as type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) in function argument
```

Any insights into what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`HandlerFunc` method on `Route`](http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Route.HandlerFunc) expects to be passed a function, as the error message indicates.  If instead you have an `http.Handler`, call [`Handler`](http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Route.Handler) instead:

```
subroutes.Methods("GET").Handler(MyHandler(renderer))
```

Or alternatively, have your `MyHandler` function return the handler function directly rather than wrapping it as an `http.Handler`.  Which option you choose is going to be a matter of style, and depend on the rest of your program.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know about .Handler. Thank you!